# Calculating the minimum distance between two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, distance, minimum

I like to find the item of DF2 that is cloest to the item in DF1.

The distance is euclidean distance.

For example, for A in DF1, F in DF2 is the cloeset one.

```
>>> DF1
   X  Y name
0  1  2    A
1  3  4    B
2  5  6    C
3  7  8    D
>>> DF2
   X  Y name
0  3  8    E
1  2  4    F
2  1  9    G
3  6  4    H
```

My code is

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'X' : [1,3,5,7],'Y' : [2,4,6,8]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],'X' : [3,2,1,6],'Y' : [8,4,9,4]})


def ndis(row):
    try:
        X,Y=row['X'],row['Y']
        DF2['DIS']=(DF2.X-X)*(DF2.X-X)+(DF2.Y-Y)*(DF2.Y-Y)
        temp=DF2.ix[DF2.DIS.idxmin()]
        return temp[2]  #       print temp[2]
    except:
        pass        


DF1['Z']=DF1.apply(ndis, axis=1)
```

This works fine, and it will take too long for large data set.

Another question is to how to find the 2nd and 3d cloeset ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one approach, for example one can use numpy:

```
>>> xy = ['X', 'Y']
>>> distance_array = numpy.sum((df1[xy].values - df2[xy].values)**2, axis=1)
>>> distance_array.argmin()
1
```

Top 3 closest (not the fastest approach, I suppose, but simplest)

```
>>> distance_array.argsort()[:3]
array([1, 3, 2])
```

If speed is a concern, run performance tests.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [scipy.spatial.KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) and the related cKDTree, which is faster but offers only a subset of the functionality. For large sets, you probably won't beat that for speed.